# Aw, snap from google chrome - no fix in sight

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I get the "Aw, snap" error in Google Chrome as soon as it starts up on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

These are the things I've tried to resolved it.

1. Completely remove chrome and reinstall from package manager
2. Step 1, + remove `.config/google-chrome` from my home directory.
3. Blow away `/opt/google/chrome` and and 2 and reinstall from scratch.
4. Step 3 + try chrome beta.
5. Step 3 + try chromium.
6. try fixing the nss errors and try again.
7. `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and try 3.
8. start chrome with `--single-process && --no-proxy-server`
9. Check set symbolic link in `/opt/google/chrome` for `libudev.so.0`
10. Swapped the graphics card.
11. Install `libnss-myhostname`

No matter what I do, it always shows Aw, snap as soon as it loads.  It won't even allow browsing chrome:plugins etc.  It's as though chrome or  the chrome packages are just completely broken on Ubuntu 14.04.  But other people have it running.  I don't see anything obvious.

My current solution is - use firefox.

I wish I could find a fix.  I'm wanting to run chrome for testing.

```
~$ /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --diagnostics 
[PASS] Install type
       System Level
[PASS] Chrome version test
       43.0.2357.130 GCB
[PASS] User data path
       Path exists and is writable: 3918988
[PASS] Local state path
       Path exists and is writable: 20165
[PASS] App dictionaries directory path
       Path exists
[PASS] Resources path
       Path exists
[PASS] Available disk space
       Free space: 664697888768
[PASS] User preferences integrity
       File parsed OK
[PASS] Local state integrity
       File parsed OK
[PASS] Bookmark file
       File not found (but that is OK)
[PASS] Web Data database
       No corruption detected
[PASS] Cookie database
       No corruption detected
[PASS] History database
       No corruption detected
[PASS] Thumbnails database
       File not found (but that is OK)
[PASS] Database tracker database
       No corruption detected
Finished 15 tests.

~$ rm -rf .pki/
~$ rm -rf .config/google-chrome/
~$ /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome 
[6:6:0624/155528:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[6:6:0624/155528:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
[8:8:0624/155528:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[8:8:0624/155528:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
[10:10:0624/155528:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[10:10:0624/155528:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
[12:12:0624/155528:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[12:12:0624/155528:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
[14:14:0624/155528:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[14:14:0624/155528:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
[16:16:0624/155529:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[16:16:0624/155529:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidia0 (Operation not permitted).
NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidia0 (Operation not permitted).
NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidia0 (Operation not permitted).
[21:21:0624/155531:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[21:21:0624/155531:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
[24:24:0624/155533:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[24:24:0624/155533:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
[26:26:0624/155533:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[26:26:0624/155533:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
[28:28:0624/155534:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[28:28:0624/155534:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidia0 (Operation not permitted).
NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidia0 (Operation not permitted).
NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidia0 (Operation not permitted).
[33:33:0624/155537:ERROR:nss_util.cc(207)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -8023
[33:33:0624/155537:FATAL:nss_util.cc(209)] nss_error=-8023, os_error=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know I'm not directly answering the question about Chromium.. but after trying a number of steps without success, I stumbled on [“Aw, Snap!” Chrome Web Store (Chromium)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548605/aw-snap-chrome-web-store-chromium)
and I purged Chromium from my system and installed the standard the Google Chrome .deb downloaded from Google. Now I have Chrome without the Aw, Snap on startup.

Here are some of the steps in case it is helpful to anyone..

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

Downloaded "google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb" from [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) and installed it.

It lists as version 40.0.2214.115-1 for my install:

```
sudo dpkg-query -l "google-chrome*"
...
google-chrome-stable 40.0.2214.115-1  amd64 The web browser from Google
```

Comment: I actually did a full purge as well. And then installed the deb from google.  The problem persists.  My fix?  switch to firefox.  I think there must be some broken library that chrome uses that is causing this.

Comment: Same goes with mine too. Still haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: And I still haven't found a solution.  Chrome is totally broken!

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same issue and also, none of the solutions i found worked.
In my case i needed to install a 32bit chrome version. Well.. purging the chrome installation and installing the 48 version it worked... if it is of any help for someone here's the download link i used: http://bbgentoo.ilb.ru/distfiles/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb

Comment: -1 for suggesting the installation of an **old, unsupported and insecure web browser**. Please don't do that!